# How can you set a Function App to use secure transfer to storage accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

The policy requiring secure transfer to storage accounts has been enabled, so we're getting the validation error that it should be enabled.

But there doesn't seem to be anyway to enabled for the function app in the Portal?

Or is this something that can only be set on the function apps properties using ARM?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable secure transfer for your Azure storage accounts, just go to your **storage accounts => Configuration => Secure transfer required** to turn on it .Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-require-secure-transfer#enable-secure-transfer-required-in-the-azure-portal) . Once it is enabled , your storage account will reject all http requests , you should use https to access your storage account . What's more , custom domain is not supported for your storage account any more as Azure storage doesn’t support HTTPs for custom domain names. 
If you have any further concerns , pls feel free to let me know.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear. I want to set the function app to send https, not how to enable the storage account to only accept https

Comment: Hi @SteveC ,could you pls have a check that if the setting you looking for : Your Azure function > Platform features > Custom Domains > toggle HTTPS Only to 'On' ? If not , could you pls provide some details that how you got that error ?

Comment: Stan, I think that setting applies to calls TO the function app are redirected to HTTPS, rather than ensuring any function app calls to underlying storage account are done over HTTPS

Comment: Hi Steve, may I know how you access your storage account in your function code ?